# Using both GCM and FCM in the same App

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

In our App, We would like to update our current GCM implementation for Push notifications to the newer FCM implementation. But, we are also using a third-party tool to run campaigns, whose SDK still uses GCM. What will be the harm in using both GCM and FCM in the same App?

I tried to look up this info in the Firebase documentation, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Can you provide an idea on how this *3rd party tool* works with GCM? Maybe there's just minor configuration needed for it to also work with FCM. When it comes to the ***harm***, I'm not entirely sure, but isn't it redundant to implement both? There is no actual need (although it is preferred) to migrate to FCM if you don't want to.

Comment: @AL. That is regular GCM implementation done by their own SDK which is included in our project. We are moving to FCM to take advantage of the new "notification" payload which will be taken care by the play services itself to show notification when the App is in background and also to use "Firebase notifications" to run our campaigns to user segments.

Comment: The `notification` payload has been available for GCM even before FCM started. See [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive). What type of user segments are you planning to use?

Comment: @AL. Thanks for sharing the article on how to use notification payload in the GCM itself. We are using multiple Firebase services like its db, remote config, analytics etc. It is better to implement FCM not only to stay in that Firebase env but also Google already announced that only FCM will have new feature updates not GCM.

Comment: I see. That's great that you're trying to utilize Firebase. :) Well, other than the redundancy, I can't think of anything else that can harm your app. What is this 3rd party tool that you are using anyways?